# Docker image doesnt retain changed information

Tags: docker, docker-image

OK so my requirement is to modify the docker image. Following are my steps:

1. Pull the docker image
2. Run the container.
3. Step into the container and modified the file.
4. Create an image from container
5. Stop the container
6. Rerun the container with new image.

I was expecting the file i had modified should be updated, but its not. Is there anything i am missing ?

Comment: The sequence you describe is not especially a best practice.  Imagine there's a critical security update in the base image, and you _must_ take the update or have your entire environment compromised.  Will you be able to repeat the manual sequence of steps exactly?  Better practice is to write a Dockerfile that you can commit to source control and `docker build` as needed; see background material like Docker's [Sample application](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/) tutorial for some examples of this sequence.

Comment: What's the exact sequence of commands you are issuing on the terminal?

Comment: @johndee31415
docker pull 
docker run
docker exec <containerid> -t -i /bin/bash
vim <file name>
--update file
exit
docker commit <containerid> <example:latest>
docker run -it --name example_app example_image

Comment: What about the line `vim <file name> --update file exit`?  Is this a valid bash/vim command?

Comment: @johndee31415 not exatcly, actually these are three steps to update the file. 1. vim <file name>, 2. update the file, 3. exit from docker

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete you image docker with `docker rmi <imagename>` for list all images run `docker images`

Comment: delete the original ?

Comment: yes and you can re build image